# Linear combination of the rows of a matrix with all resulting components different to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, combinations

I have a matrix with *n* rows and every column has at least one non-zero element. I want to produce a linear combination of the rows (preferably one that contains the smallest coefficients possible) such that the resulting combination has no zero components. Is there a way to obtain this analytically?

I have come up with an algorithm that yields an answer but I am not sure if it is the most efficient/optimal solution: Firstly it selects a row and adds it to the first row of the matrix. It keeps adding this row until no components get canceled out. It then moves to the next row and repeats the previous steps until the end of the matrix.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you require the coefficients in the linear combination to be integers? Positive integers? If you have them as real numbers (or even rational numbers), then there will be no "smallest" coefficients.

Comment: Also, given that there are $n$ coefficients, what do you mean by "smallest possible"? Are you trying to minimise the largest absolute value among the $n$ coefficients, or something else?

Comment: The coefficients could be real numbers.

By "smallest possible" I am trying to express that it would be preferable that no coefficient is arbitrarily made larger in comparison to the other coefficients. I think that the best way of expressing this is that if the matrix is 2x2, then the result should be as close as possible to the 45 degree line.
 
If these comments make the problem more clear, I can edit the original question. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Well then, essentially what you should do is add all the rows together (giving you coefficients of all $1$s). If the result has no $0$s, then you have found an optimal solution. If the result does have $0$s, then there will be no optimal solution.

Comment: I don't think that is valid. Assume the following rows: [ 1. -1. -1. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.] [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.  0.] [ 0.  0.  1.  0. -1. -1.  0.  1. -1.  0.] [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0. -1.], Summing all rows yields [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. -1.]. Two possible solutions are [ 1  1  2  1 -1 -2 -1  1 -1 -1] and [ 1 1 99  1 -98 -99 -1 98 -98 -1]. The former is considered more "optimal" than the latter because it forms a smaller angle with [0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316 0.316].

Comment: Wait, so you want the entries in the row, not the coefficients, to be as close to a $1$ row as possible?

Comment: Correct. Sorry for not making myself more clear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is your $m \times n$ matrix. From what I've gathered from our comments, what you want to be doing is projecting the vector $j \in \Bbb{R}^m$ containing only $1$s onto the rowspace of $A$. In this way, you'll obtain a linear combination that is as close to $j$ as possible, in terms of the Euclidean $2$-norm.

I suggest considering $(A^\top)^+ = (A^+)^\top$, the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A^\top$. Essentially, we want a least squares approximation of the matrix equation
$$A^\top x = j$$
where $x$ is an arbitrary $m \times 1$ column vector, consisting of coefficients in the linear combination of rows (also, $j$ is considered a column vector). Then, if $w$ is an arbitrary $m \times 1$ column vector, choosing
$$x = (A^\top)^+j + (I - (A^\top)^+A^\top)w$$
will produce an optimal linear combination. In particular, we can choose $w = 0$, and simply use
$$x = (A^\top)^+j.$$
If the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, then the pseudoinverse is straight forward to compute:
$$(A^\top)^+ = (AA^\top)^{-1}A.$$
Thus, you may want to consider removing rows that are linearly dependent on the others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not entirely sure that this solution scheme would ensure that the elements of the projection x are different to zero.

Comment: That's a good point. I had actually forgotten about that requirement. However, if this fails, and produces a vector with $0$ entries, then small perturbations will produce vectors without zero entries. All you'll be able to get is a sequence of suboptimal solutions without $0$ entries that converge to the optimal solution with $0$ entries.

Comment: How would you produce the small perturbations? It seems to me that it would be framed exactly as the original problem. The perturbation itself should be a linear combination of the rows, it should try not to move the solution vector too much away from the vector containing all 1s and should not produce new zeros in the final solution vector.

Comment: OK, so I've found a way to make your linear combination of rows as close to the $1$ vector as possible. My comment was about finding a linear combination of rows as close to the $1$ vector as possible subject to the restriction that all the entries are non-$0$, is probably impossible, unless the answer is the unrestricted vector (which would have to happen not to have $0$s in that particular case). So, either my method works and produces an acceptable solution, or there is no optimal solution. There will be feasible solutions, as close as you like to optimal, but no optimal solution.

Comment: If you don't care about optimality, then you can use your method to work out a solution. If you want it to be close to optimal, I suggest applying the method in my answer to find the optimal solution (possibly with $0$s), and adding only very small multiples of rows as per your method, until all the $0$s are no longer $0$. Try to make the perturbations small relative to $n$ times the largest entry in the matrix.

Comment: You are right. There is a set of equally optimal solutions. I think that if I take your answer, evaluate what vector I would need to add to prevent any 0 components in the final solution, select the row that has the smallest projection into that correction and then scale it by an arbitrarily small factor then I would obtain a good enough answer. I will implement it in my code and let you know how it goes. Thank you so much for the help!